# Nest.js API endpoint for validating the POST data

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

I want to validate the entity data separately from making a POST request and display errors in the form. I'm using `class-transformer`. What's the best way to achieve this with Nest?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds exactly like what the [ValidationPipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) is for. You decorate your DTO with class-validator decorators, set the `@Body()` type in your endpoint, and bind the pipe and viola, the request gets validated when sent to the server and returns errors that you can parse if any exist

Comment: I'm already using it, I was just wondering if there's a proper architectural solution for doing a **separate** partial validation request **before** user submits the form? So say I have a field that is supposed to be unique, and I want to validate it on blur & notify the user of this problem before they proceed to the next field. Or a separate `/check-if-project-name-is-unique` endpoint in this case is the way to go?

Comment: That would be something you take care of on the client side, right? Why would you create a separate endpoint just for payload validation when you do that exact same payload validation on the regular endpoint? Instead, you should make similar validation rules in your UI form and set up notifications there if there are problems

Comment: Yeah but checking for uniqueness requires a database query, which you can't do on the client side

Comment: So make the uniqueness check part of the business logic on submit. OR if you absolutely really think you need this, make some sort of intermediary GET requests that checks for that field, and that field only, and it's uniqueness value. Seems like a lot of effort and HTTP time, but if it's what you want to do then go for it